LED Strip with Jeston Orin
I’m trying to program a WS2815 strip using the Jetson Orin GPIO. I was able to do it on a raspberry pi using this library GitHub - https://github.com/hajimef/ws2815test_rpi using Raspberry Pi GPIO library for WS281X LEDs 113, but it seems there’s no easy way of doing it on the Orin and there literally no resource in it.
Does anyone know of a RGB LED type that we can interact with the jetson Orin preferably using the python GPIO library? GitHub - NVIDIA/jetson-gpio: A Python library that enables the use of Jetson's GPIOs 37
https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-gpio
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/python-circuitpython
I have tried everything none of the package seems to work on the led strip.
